# What happens to a function with multiple x terms when one is changed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, what happens to the function $f(x) = x^2 - 5x + 3$ when one x term gets changed, but not the others(example: the function $ g(x) =(x-2)^2 - 5x + 3$). I know what happens when all of the x terms are changed by the same amount but what happens if only one gets changed?(as in, does it get translated(if so, how does it get translated), or transformed, or what)

Comment: You get a different function. It's not clear what kind of answer you'd  expect to `what happens`.

Comment: In this case, we have $g(x)=(x-2)^2-5x+3=(x-2)^2-5(x-2)+3-10=f(x-2)-10$, so $(x,f(x))$ is shifted to $(x-2,g(x)+10)$, thus the graph of $g(x)$ is just the graph of $f(x)$ shifted horizontally by $-2$ units and vertically by $-10$ units.

Comment: This feels like a philosophical question rather than a mathematical one. If the $x$ in the definitions of $f(x)$ is the same  as the $x$ in the definition of $g(x)$, then changing the value of $x$ should change both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. e.g., if $x = 0$, then $f(x) = 3$, $g(x) = 7$. But if $x = 1$, then $f(x) = -1$, $g(x) = -1$.

Comment: For these two specific functions, it might help you to go to Wolfram Alpha and put in `plot x^2 - 5x + 3 and (x - 2)^2 - 5x + 3`.

Comment: Typo: horizontally by $+2$ units and vertically by $-10$ units.